# How to redirect in nginx, if users enter the website with trailing slash at the end in the path?

Tags: nginx, redirect, webserver, gatsby, nginx-location

here we are having a gatsby website, where we facing some redirection problems. Like

Eg:

if i enter `https://example.com/test/` -> it is redirecting to `https://example.com/test`.

But in https://www.redirect-checker.org/ it showing

`https://example.com/test/` as a HTTP Status Code of 200 instead of 301. So its affecting the SEO of duplicate pages.

**Expectation is**

if we enter `https://example.com/test/`

First, it redirects to `https://example.com/test/` as a HTTP Status Code of 301

Then it redirects to `https://example.com/test` as a HTTP Status code of 200.

Here i changed my `nginx.conf` file like this (`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`).

```
server {


listen 80;


location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  error_page 404 /404.html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;



location = /50x.html {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

}
```

Still, I am getting `https://example.com/test/` path as a status code of 200 instead of 301. Could anyone pls help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a `rewrite` rule `permanent`? Something like:

```
 server {

    listen       81 default_server;
    listen       [::]:81 default_server;
    server_name  example.ubuntu.com;


    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    root         /home/your/path/to/public/folder/public;


    index index.html;


    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try using [`gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes/) which is not a definitive solution but it may work for your use-case.